# Maximum number of views per document library?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

What is the maximum number of views per document library?

Comment: Please define if it's SharePoint 2010 or 2013, or something else. Not that the answer would be any different, but still.

Comment: Sorry, SharePoint 2103 Enterprise

Comment: If you hit the limit of <whatever> views per document library, you may be doing something wrong. Try to get a handle on how the views differ. Consider creating pages instead of views, and create a page with links. A page URL can contain one or more URL parameters. These parameters can be passed on as filter parameters to the query that builds the view.

Answer (score 2):

I know its very late to answer but still it can save someone's time.

Actually we don’t have any limit for the view creation on Document Library whether you are creating **Public View** or **Private (Personal) View**.

But there is limit of 50 to show the ***views*** dropdown. It doesn't mean that you cannot jump to **51th** view, you can go with the help of URL.

The above limit is for both , **Private and Public View**.

You can get more detailed information about the limit of Views in Document Library in SharePoint 2013 from below mentioned article.

[View Limits in SharePoint 2013](https://www.kintivo.com/view-limits-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Or else you can go through [Maximum number of views per document library in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174662/maximum-number-of-views-per-document-library-in-sharepoint-2013)

Actually a single user can have maximum of 50 views (**Personal View**) on single page as the limitation is 50 WebPart per page.

Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

In 2007 and 2010 the limit was 50.

Comment: And in 2013 it is?