# Maximum number of views per document library in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list-view

What is the maximum number of views we can create per document library? it was limited to 50 views in 2010 but I want to know the limit for SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two types of views - Public and Private.

**Public View:** To create Public Views there doesn’t appear to be an actual limit. What was limited in previous version of SharePoint 2010 is the number of views shown in the drop-down list of views. The limit was 50. You can have more than 50 views but to navigate to view 51 you should be knowing the URL. And if you didn’t know the URL of the view, you could still get to it from the List Settings or Library Settings.

**Private View:** Similarly there is no limit to the number of Personal Views ​that can be created on a list or document library. But here we have an actual physical limit on the number of Personal Views per person. Unlike Public views, there is no separate page for each Personal View, instead there is a separate page for each person. The limitation is 50 web part limit per page in SharePoint, an individual user may only have 50 Personal Views before an error is thrown, an error like below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That limit was 50 in the(...) dropdown. Just because they didn’t show up in the list, didn’t mean you couldn’t still have them, though. Each Public View has its own page. If you know the URL to that page, you can get to the view… you just won’t be able to access more than 50 from the dropdown.

Please refer the Link for Limits of Lists & Library views
[View Limits](http://www.kintivo.com/view-limits-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Please avoid short answers only with an link. A description would be better in case the link expires.