# New web part view does not show in the drop-down

Tags: web-part, view

When trying to apply a new view to a web part through the browser, the new view does not appear in the drop-down. This web part has many views. Any ideas on how to make the new view appear in the drop-down? Or what controls the number of views that show up in the drop-down?

Comment: Possible duplicate question.
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79592/not-all-views-being-displayed-in-my-web-part

Comment: Also, verify the view you want to show is a public view not a personal view.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to create more views, when the web part is edited, the view drop-down is limited to the first 50 views created. Solution is to either edit the current view or in SP Designer, click on web part, then Filter, then adjust view criteria.

[Maximum number of views per document library in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174662/maximum-number-of-views-per-document-library-in-sharepoint-2013/174670#174670)